# c double pointer giving error that doesn't make sense

Tags: c, pointers

```
int p_entity(char **data){
  char *pch;

  pch = strtok(*data, " \n");
  // printf("%s ", pch);
  pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
  // (*data) = (*data) + 1;   // 1. this is okay
  //  (*data) = pch;          // 2. but doing this will cause an error
  printf("%c %d \n", *pch, pch); 
  printf("%c %d \n", **data, *data);
}
```

From the above code I will get the following if I uncomment 1:

```
g 4927479
e 4927456
```

I will get the following if I uncomment 2:

```
g 4927479
g 4927479
      3 [main] main 8172 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    470 [main] main 8172 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to main.exe.stackdump
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting that error? I would think both assignments would be legal and incrementing (*data) would be equivalent to straight assignning the address I want it to be at.

Comment: what sort of evil code is that? :)  why are you even passing as char**? why are you trying to reassign (*data) ?

Comment: this is... oy. this code is scary beyond words.

Comment: Identifiers like `entity`, `data`, `pch` for "pointer to char" come straight from http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html

Comment: I am writing a code beautifier, so I load the file into memory and begin priting it out in a beautified format. So *data is the location of the current position in the memory. **data is the actual current char. So I pass this function the current location on **data, and I process it, then I move foward in the data by incrementing *data. The think I don't understand is that I can increment *data but I can't directly assign it an address.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like even when you get the error (and uncomment 2), you still get the two printfs... seems like it is crashing much later in your code.

Comment: I think error happens when I try to leave the function, something gets popped out of the stack that shouldn't or something by assigning the location ch to *data

Answer (score 0):

Answer really depends on how you are handling data before and after calling this function.

if you are allocating memory to *data before calling this function and tying to free it after this function returns, it could crash, as you have changed its value.